# Lightweight MySQL Qt GUI frontend for Linux

Tags: mysql, gui, qt, frontend

I'm looking for a lightweight MySQL Qt4/PyQt4 GUI frontend for Linux.

Ideally it will be very similar to [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/).

I did some google searches but it only finds Java monsters and herds of shareware MySQL GUIs for Windows.

Comment: Does it have to be free?

Comment: @musicfreak: Yes, free (both as in beer and as in freedom) and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not equal huge. Why don't you actually try a few before shooting down the whole language?

Answer (score 0):

How about [sqlyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/) Community edition ?

Comment: I don't think it uses Qt4, and it's Windows-only...

Answer (score 0):

[Emma](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/emma-graphical-toolkit-for-mysql-database-developers-and-administrators.html)

or MySQL Query Browser

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.