# Alternative to MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, gui

Is there a free alternative to MySQL Workbench? I really need a visual database designer that doesn't crash every five minutes.

Comment: What [OS](http://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/) are you on?

Comment: I'm using both Ubuntu and Windows :-)

Comment: did you try some of these? http://superuser.com/questions/164904/lightweight-mysql-qt-gui-frontend-for-linux

Comment: mine doesn't - what I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: soooooo @random... :P

Comment: @Mehrdad This question is *exactly* what the SE network does not want. Do you see anything valuable except for an indefinite list of "try this" one-line answers?

Comment: @slhck: Well, personally, I actually *like* one-line answers, so long as they actually answer the OP's question (and the OP finds them useful). I don't see what's wrong with being succinct.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, they answer the question because the actual question is so vague. What else could you be answering? In this sense, they might be reasonable answers. But only good questions inspire good answers, and that's why they need to be closed so as not to attract the kind you see below. Also, SE doesn't need to become a second [alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/).

Comment: For alternatives go to [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/) whereas bugs should be reported and dealt with at [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/)

Comment: I love this one http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/

Comment: You can use [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/), there is a Database Diagram, and there many useful visual object editors. Try free Express or Trial edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best alternative to MySQL Workbench. It's called [**DbSchema**](http://www.dbschema.com/).

It never crashes and works like a charm.

> DbSchema is an integrated universal database tool, featuring graphical layouts, Relational Data Browse, Query Builder, SQL Editor, schema deployment and synchronization and many more.

Comment: The OP asks for a free alternative. DBSchema has a free edition but it is rather limited (12 tables only and other limitations).

Comment: It never crashes... *ever* is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Check this link for a nice GUI Tool for MySQL.

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)

[image]

> SQLyog MySQL GUI is a MySQL manager and admin tool, combining the features of MySQL Administrator, phpMyAdmin and other MySQL Front Ends and MySQL GUI tools.

Comment: You should mention this tool is not free, ranging from 99$ to 3999$, and thus your answer is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this free utility called HeidiSQL:

http://www.heidisql.com/

Here's another one called EMS MySQL Manager:

http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/studio/mysql

Answer (score 1):

I've been using MySQL Workbench for a little over a year now. I use it for several hours each day. It used to crash on me on a daily basis however it has improved significantly in the last 6 months or so. I'm not sure if you're aware but every few weeks they release a new minor version. The latest version is 5.2.37 and it's been working quite well for me. If you haven't updated your installation please consider that before searching for an alternative.

Comment: Just a note, the mac version is still horrific at this time (version 5.2.41).

Comment: it is 2016 @MrJre, that's sadly still the case now...im moving backward to try to go forward.

Answer (score 1):

Also...

[squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org) is a Java/JDBC database tool. It isn't database specific, but you can use with whatever DB you have JDBC drivers for. Clunky at times, but useful.

[Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/) which can be used within eclipse or as a standalone client. It also uses JDBC.